# what is the solution for Android AVD struggling for opening

Tags: android

I installed eclipse adt bundle . first time the avd is working fine . i can go through all option in avd like settings, adding goolge account. but once i opened any web page in my internet explorer page, the avd will be gone.it becomes very slow to open again. please any one guide me in this

Answer (score 0):

Install genymotion - http://www.genymotion.com/ which is much faster than AVD and has more feature compare to Android emulators.